About Aharonov-Bohm effect without path integral approach
I'm currently reading the book Quantum Paradoxes: Quantum Theory for the Perplexed by Aharonov and Rohrlich and in chapter 4 they show the existence of AB effect. I'm already familiar with the explanation through path integral, but they do it in a different manner.
First, they show how the wave function changes under gauge transformation. I have no problem to understand the electric version of the effect. But, in the magnetic case, they consider the following:

We have a conducting cylinder rotating with constant angular velocity, with a charged wire inside. The magnetic field outside cylinder is zero, but since we have magnetic flux inside it, the Vector potential cannot be zero everywhere. We can find a vector potential for this setup as
$$
\vec A = {\Phi_B \over 2\pi} \nabla \theta
$$
and this vector potential can be obtained through a gauge transform of null field $\vec A = 0$ by the gauge function $\Lambda = {\Phi_B\over 2\pi} \theta$.
Since the function $\Lambda$ is not single-valued, it is not a proper gauge transformation everywhere. But being multi-valued, we can use it as a gauge transform in separate regions, so they apply it in left side and right side of cylinder.
if $|\Psi_L^0\rangle$ is the wave function in the left side without vector potential, with the vector potential it would be
$$
|\Psi_L\rangle = e^{ie\Phi_B\theta/2\pi\hbar c} |\Psi_L^0\rangle
$$
by the same reasoning, if $|\Psi_R^0\rangle$ is the wave function in the right side without vector potential, with the vector potential it would be
$$
|\Psi_R\rangle = e^{ie\Phi_B\theta/2\pi\hbar c} |\Psi_R^0\rangle
$$
if the state before the solenoid is $1/\sqrt{2}(|\Psi_L^0\rangle+|\Psi_R^0\rangle)$, after it would be

$$
{1\over \sqrt{2}}(|\Psi_L^0\rangle+e^{ie\Phi_B/\hbar c}|\Psi_R^0\rangle)
$$
Ignoring an overall phase and considering that the phase difference between left and right partial waves are $2\pi$.

My question is: why the phase difference between left and right waves are $2\pi$, since it seems that the gauge transformation seems to be the same for both functions?
I thought to consider the multi-valued function $\theta$ as the explanation, but if we define theta being zero in the left side, it will value $\pi$ in the right side, not $2\pi$, as claimed in the last point.
I also thought that there is a typo when defining the gauge transformation for the left and right sides, but if it's the case, how should it be the right transformation?

One trouble with these arguments about vector potential having an effect on things where $B$ vanishes is that they work only with certain class of vector potentials, related to the Coulomb gauge via a gauge transformation. But we can describe the same magnetic field with a vector potential that vanishes everywhere outside the solenoid, and is non-zero only inside the solenoid. Such is not related to the Coulomb vector potential via a gradient gauge transformation, but still gives the correct magnetic field which is the only thing $A$ is required to do.

This means that either the Coulomb gauge and related gauges are the preferred ones, the only physical ones; or that the whole explanation in terms of $A$ outside the solenoid is wrong, works only accidentally for the Coulomb gauge and related, and one should seek a different explanation in terms of interaction of the solenoid with the particle.

I understand your point, indeed it seems tricky, so basically you think that it is a right result with the wrong explanation?

If any gauge is equally acceptable, don't you think that these ones are just the convenient ones? An explanation with a gauge s.t. the vector potential vanishes outside would require other means to describe such interaction (maybe virtual photons?), but in the end they would give the same result

I think it's fine for the BA shift to happen in such experiment, but the standard explanation (the BA effect) is very strange and suspicious, since it works only in some gauges, and not others. The best explanation should work irrespective of the gauge chosen, just like E,B work in EM theory. A belief in the BA effect means (is equivalent to) belief that some gauges are correct and others are not.

In the original Bohm-Aharaonov paper there is an exact series solution for a plane wave scattering off a thin solenoid:
$$
\psi(r,\theta)= \sum_{l=-\infty}^\infty e^{i(l\theta - \pi/2|l-\alpha|)} J_{|l-\alpha|}(kr)
$$
Below is  is a plot of the real part of the wavefunction for $\alpha=.25$, meaning the solenoid has 1/4 of a flux unit..
The wave is incident from the right and you can clearly see the 1/4  wavelength  wavefront offsets caused by the flux. This represents the physical effect of the "branch cut" in the gauge transformation.

Nice! I'll read it for sure. My mistake was to not going straight to the original material!

The wavefronts are quite irregularly curved, one would expect more smooth curves. What is the reason? Numerical error?

@Jan Lalainsky This is an old plot. I have used higher numerical resolutions in the pst and the plot does not change significantly --- but the latest Matthematica introduces some obvious numerical glitches apparanty due  to the implementation of ArcTan[x,y].

Another thing that seems off is this: why are the wavefronts affected only on the left-hand side, for negative $x$? The solenoid vector potential has cylindrical symmetry, so shouldn't wavefronts be affected also for positive $x$, in the right half-square? Or are they, and it's just not visible?

@Ján Lalinský  The wave is incident from the right and the solenoid only affects wave that have passed it.

But why should the solenoid affect only the wavefronts that are in the region $x<0$? When any real plane wave (e.g. water wave, or EM wave) comes to a cylindrical obstacle, the obstacle creates secondary cylindrical wave which propagates in all directions, not just in the direction of the primary radiation. This secondary wave should affect the total wave everywhere, not just "downstream".

@Ján Lalinský It does. Can you not see the circular wavefronts interfering with the plane wave?  The "seam" is downstream, and is the major place where the usual $\psi=e^{ikx}+ f(\theta)/r$ scattering solutions fails.

I should add that you can see a photograph of a bathtub vortex  in "M. V. Berry, R. G. Chambers, M. D. Large, C. Upstill, and J. C. Walmsley, Eur. J. Phys. 1, 154 (1980)", and  pictures of variants in ArXiv 1211.3751

A free version if the Berry paper is at https://michaelberryphysics.wordpress.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/berry096.pdf

@mikestone yes circular wavefronts can be seen in both halfspaces. But the seam is apparent only on the left. While on the photograph of water waves interacting with vorted, wavefronts seem to be deformed everywhere. I would expect the solenoid to have similar effect on $\psi$, to shift wavefronts everywhere around it.

The answer lies in the detail that $\theta$ is a multi-valued function, i.e.,
$$
\theta (\mathbf r) = \theta + 2\pi n, \quad n\in \mathbb Z,
$$
for all points $\mathbf r$ in space.
The curve $\theta = 0$ is the branch point, so the Gauge transform for $|\psi_L\rangle$ and $|\psi_R\rangle$ seems to give them phase at first sight, but in fact they differs from $2\pi$ because they lie in opposite sites of the branch cut (it should be true, otherwise the vector potential would be a gradient field in this region and the magnetic field would be null, which is a contradiction). The book don't let it clear, but the equation above justify the book's affirmations and we could write
$$
|\Psi_L\rangle = e^{ie\Phi_B \theta/2\pi \hbar c}|\Psi_L^0\rangle, \quad |\Psi_R\rangle = e^{ie\Phi_B(\theta + 2\pi)/2\pi \hbar c}|\Psi_R^0\rangle.
$$
The phase difference between the two slits is $e^{ie\Phi_B/\hbar c}$, which agrees with the book claims and the result obtained through path integrals.
